# I have list of list .In that i want to make a list from list before empty list

Tags: python-3.x

```
l1 = [['11-Aug-2020', 'Purchase', '19,999.00', '8.977', '2,227.7094', '8.977'], ['11-Aug-2020'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['1.00'], [''], ['09-Aug-2020', 'Purchase', '-', 'via', 'Distributor', '19,999.00', '5.075', '3,940.6116', '5.075'], ['09-Aug-2020'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['1.00'], ['10-Aug-2020'], ['Address', 'Updated', 'from', 'KRA', 'Data'], [''], [''], ['23-Nov-2020', 'SIP', 'Purchase', 'Distributor/AXISBANK', '999.95', '36.033', '27.75090000', '36.033'], ['23-Nov-2020'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['0.05'], ['24-Nov-2020'], ['Address', 'Updated', 'from', 'KRA', 'Data'], [''], ['01-Jan-2021', 'SIP', 'Purchase', 'Distributor/AXISBANK', '999.95', '35.752', '27.96910000', '71.785'], ['01-Jan-2021'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['0.05'], ['01-Feb-2021', 'SIP', 'Purchase', 'Distributor/AXISBANK', '999.95', '36.249', '27.58580000', '108.034'], ['01-Feb-2021'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['0.05'], ['01-Mar-2021', 'SIP', 'Purchase', 'Distributor/AXISBANK', '999.95', '36.642', '27.28970000', '144.676'], ['01-Mar-2021'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['0.05'], ['05-Apr-2021', 'SIP', 'Purchase', 'Distributor/AXISBANK', '999.95', '36.216', '27.61090000', '180.892'], ['05-Apr-2021'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['0.05'], ['03-May-2021', 'SIP', 'Purchase', 'Distributor/AXISBANK', '999.95', '36.001', '27.77560000', '216.893'], ['03-May-2021'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['0.05'], ['01-Jun-2021', 'SIP', 'Purchase', 'Distributor/AXISBANK', '999.95', '35.855', '27.88910000', '252.748'], ['01-Jun-2021'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['0.05'], ['01-Jul-2021', 'SIP', 'Purchase', 'Distributor/AXISBANK', '999.95', '35.799', '27.93270000', '288.547'], ['01-Jul-2021'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['0.05'], ['02-Aug-2021', 'SIP', 'Purchase', 'Distributor/AXISBANK', '999.95', '35.622', '28.07130000', '324.169'], ['02-Aug-2021'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['0.05'], ['01-Sep-2021', 'SIP', 'Purchase', 'Distributor/AXISBANK', '999.95', '35.325', '28.30680000', '359.494'], ['01-Sep-2021'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['0.05'], ['01-Oct-2021', 'SIP', 'Purchase', 'Distributor/AXISBANK', '999.95', '35.280', '28.34360000', '394.774'], ['01-Oct-2021'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['0.05'], ['01-Nov-2021', 'SIP', 'Purchase', 'Distributor/AXISBANK', '999.95', '35.248', '28.36880000', '430.022'], ['01-Nov-2021'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['0.05'], [''], ['11-Jun-2021', 'Purchase', '199,990.00', '12,151.168', '16.4585', '12,151.168'], ['11-Jun-2021'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['10.00'], ['14-Jun-2021'], ['Address', 'Updated', 'from', 'KRA', 'Data'], [''], ['']]
```

i want

```
lk = [[['11-Aug-2020', 'Purchase', '19,999.00', '8.977', '2,227.7094', '8.977'], ['11-Aug-2020'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['1.00']] ,[['09-Aug-2020', 'Purchase', '-', 'via', 'Distributor', '19,999.00', '5.075', '3,940.6116', '5.075'], ['09-Aug-2020'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['1.00'], ['10-Aug-2020'], ['Address', 'Updated', 'from', 'KRA', 'Data'],]]
```

like that using python

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Below code transforms the input for your expected output:

```
result = []
current = []

for item in l1:
    if item != ['']:
        current.append(item)
    elif current:
        result.append(current)
        current = []
    else:
        break

print(result)
```

This will output:

```
[[['11-Aug-2020', 'Purchase', '19,999.00', '8.977', '2,227.7094', '8.977'], ['11-Aug-2020'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['1.00']], [['09-Aug-2020', 'Purchase', '-', 'via', 'Distributor', '19,999.00', '5.075', '3,940.6116', '5.075'], ['09-Aug-2020'], ['Stamp', 'Duty'], ['1.00'], ['10-Aug-2020'], ['Address', 'Updated', 'from', 'KRA', 'Data']]]
```

Comment: If all looks good, can you please set it as accepted answer? Thank you!